# Uploading a File on aWebsite using Ruby Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 4 and I have this code.

I created a controller and called it upload (upload_controller.rb)

I put this code in it:

```
 class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
  render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.rhtml.erb'
  end

   def uploadFile
   post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
   render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"

   end
 end
```

My model was called data_file.rb.  The code is the following:

```
 class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :upload
   def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
     directory = "public/data"
     # create the file path
     path = File.join(directory, name)
     # write the file
     File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
   end

 end
```

My view file was called uploadFile.html.erb.  My code is the following:

```
 <h1>File Upload</h1>
 <%= form_tag({:action => 'uploadFile'}, :multipart => true) do %>
     <p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label>
       <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
     <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
 <% end %>
```

My main goal of having this code is so that the user can upload a file to a specified location.  The file type has to be anything not just images but doc, excel sheets, etc.  Once I write this code and I do bundle install and then I do rake db:migrate and I go to tools and run the development.  Once I do that I go to firefox and type in localhost:3000 and the page cannot show.  (directs me to yahoo search or whatever).

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.  Am I suppose to add a gem or change a certain line or something?  I have been stuck on this issue for days now and I just want to move on to the next part of my webpage. Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like your server isn't running if nothing is happening at localhost:3000. Did you start it?

Comment: yeah did you type 'rails s' in console within your rails app directory?